# Proving set $W$ is neither open nor closed

Tags: general-topology

This question is from page 86 Wayne Patty's Topology and I was unable to solve 1 part of th efollowing question.

> Question: Let $X_n =\mathbb{R}$ and let $T_n$ denote the usual topology on $X_n$ and $T$ be the product topology on $X=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ .Define for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $W_n$ the open interval $(0,1)$ and let $W=\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W_n$.

Show that $W$ is neither open nor closed in $(0,1)$.

well $W_i$ are open sets in $T_i$ and so why is product not open in T?

It means that this argument doesn't extends in product topology.

> But Why(kindly give a complete argument or add a source where I can look)? and how can I disprove the question ?

I am adding another relevant problem which I have in mind: Let $X_n =\mathbb{R}$ and let $T_n$ denote the usual topology on $X_n$ and T be the product topology on $X=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ .Define for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $W_n$ the closed interval [0,1] and let $W=\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W_n$.

Is $W$ closed in $(X,T)$?

Please forgive me if I am asking many questions which are not of advanced level but i did a course on topology last year and that was totally marred by a non-serious professor and I read the book again in free time. I wasn't aware of this website earlier.

Comment: Ben: Thinking of the answer yourself, using the definition of the product topology, is the purpose of this exercise. (Having us to it for you is like having someone do your push-ups for you.  That doesn't improve your arm muscles.)

Comment: @GEdgar Ok , ya you are right. I should have thought more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lbrace(X_\alpha,T_\alpha):\alpha\in\Lambda\rbrace$ is a family of topological spaces, then the product topology of $\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda}X_{\alpha}$ is the topology genereted by the sets of the form $\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda}B_{\alpha}$, such that $B_\alpha\in T_{\alpha}$ and $B_\alpha=X_\alpha$ except for a finite subset of $\Lambda$. Since $W_n\neq R$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ it is clear that $W$ doesn't contain any of the generators of the product topology, hence it cannot be an open set.

Now for your other question indeed $W$ is a closed set, if we define the sets $W'_i=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ such that $B_n=\mathbb R$ for $n\neq i$ and $B_i=[0,1]$ it is clear that this set is closed (fast-check that the compliment is open by the above definition), and $W=\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}W_i'$, since arbitrary intersection of a closed set is closed we have that $W$ is closed.

Comment: In general if for every $X_\alpha$ we take a closed set $B_\alpha$ then $\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda} B_\alpha$ is a closed subset of $\prod_{\alpha\in\Lambda}X_{\alpha}$ under the product topology

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology